# How do I turn 'n'% to '0.n' in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe where some of the columns are displayed as percentages of previous columns. I would either like to multiply them out such that:

100,000   68%

Becomes

100,000   68,000

or

100,000   0.68

Is there a way of doing this across an entire dataframe?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Sfy.png)

I have tried gsub and sub functions but they have returned the dataframe converted into a list without the intended changes. When trying to turn this list back into a dataframe the new dataframe only has one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version of the response of @Andre_Wildberg, but using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate test data
set.seed(42)    
df <- data.frame(
  Total.Population = sample(1000:20000, 10), 
  One.race = paste0(round(runif(10) * 100, digits=2), "%"), 
  etc = paste0(round(runif(10) * 100, digits=2), "%")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace_all(.x, "%", "")))
```

Using `across` make it easy to select the columns you want to transform. Here I transform all the columns with `everything()`, but you can replace it with `c("One.race", "etc")` to manually select the columns, or `starts_with("One")`, etc... (see [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html))

Of course you can also write `~as.numeric(str_replace_all(.x, "%", ""))` to transform to numeric, or even write a complete function instead of a lambda.

**EDIT:**

To apply this to your problem, you can do this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      !any_of("Total.Population"),
      ~as.numeric(str_replace_all(.x, "%", "")) * 0.01 * Total.Population
    )
  )
```

This will transform all your columns except your population as percent then multiply by the population.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Upon trying out this method, the numbers are shown as 48 without the '%' which is great but I was wondering if there was a quick way to as 0. as a prefix within the same line such that 48% -> 0.48. There are multiple columns throughout the data that are not % so changing it in a different line may not work.

Comment: Sorry I missed this part of your question. If the whole column have %, you can just multiply by 0.01 the result, for example: `mutate(across(c("your_column_1", "your_column_2"), ~as.numeric(str_replace_all(.x, "%", ""))*0.01))`

Comment: Ah i see thank you! i didn't realise it could just be added in.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all columns except the first have percentages, so only excluding the first

If this is the data

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(Total.Population = sample(1000:20000, 10), 
  One.race = paste0(round(runif(10) * 100, digits=2), "%"), 
  etc = paste0(round(runif(10) * 100, digits=2), "%"))

df
   Total.Population One.race    etc
1             19752    47.5%  44.7%
2             10289   56.03%  83.6%
3              2251    90.4% 73.76%
4             16505   13.87% 81.11%
5              9825   98.89% 38.81%
6             11288   94.67% 68.52%
7             14439    8.24%  0.39%
8             15359   51.42% 83.29%
9             17739   39.02%  0.73%
10             8699   90.57% 20.77%
```

Changing with `sub` and `as.numeric`

```
data.frame(Total.Population = df$Total.Population, 
           Vectorize(\(x) as.numeric(sub("%", "", x)) * .01)(df[,-1]))
   Total.Population One.race    etc
1             19752   0.4750 0.4470
2             10289   0.5603 0.8360
3              2251   0.9040 0.7376
4             16505   0.1387 0.8111
5              9825   0.9889 0.3881
6             11288   0.9467 0.6852
7             14439   0.0824 0.0039
8             15359   0.5142 0.8329
9             17739   0.3902 0.0073
10             8699   0.9057 0.2077
```